# React - Conditionally change the style of an element based on its own position

Tags: reactjs, jsx, use-ref, getboundingclientrect

I'm trying to change the opacity of an element based on its own position (show it only if its bigger than 500px):

```
export const Card = ({ pic }) => {
    const card = useRef(null);
    return (
        <li
            ref={card}
            style={{opacity: 500 > card.current.getBoundingClientRect().y ? 1 : 0}}
        >
            <img src={pic} />
        </li>
    );
};
```

But I got this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')**

And could not figure out how to access its position currectly.

Thanks!

Comment: `card.current` is null. You need to do a null check before you compare the (potential) value with anything.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t read the current value during rendering, as said in the [documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs)

> During the first render, the DOM nodes have not yet been created, so
> ref.current will be null. And during the rendering of updates, the DOM
> nodes haven’t been updated yet. So it’s too early to read them.

You could use state instead

```
const Card = ({pic}) => {
    const card = useRef(null);
    const [y, setY] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        setY(card.current.getBoundingClientRect().y)
    }, [])

    return (
        <li
            ref={card}
            style={{opacity: 500 > y ? 1 : 0}}
        >
            <img src={pic} />
        </li>
    );
};
```